# Unity OpenGL Renderer

Tags: opengl, unity-game-engine

How do i set a Untiy windows application to use a OpenGL render.

I need to create a plugin similar to the Texture Plugin example on this page:

http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/Plugins.html

It states:  (note that this will only work when Unity is using an OpenGL renderer)

But i cant find where in Unity i actually set it to use opengl rather the direct3d

Answer (score 3):

Based on a bit of googling, and digging through the Unity Forums, it appears that, by default, Unity will use DirectX on Windows, unless there's an issue with DirectX (either it's not there, or the wrong version), in which case it will fall back to OpenGL.  It will default to OpenGL on other platforms.

You can apparently force Unity to use OpenGL mode by launching it with the option `-force opengl`.  This option does not seem to work if you're using the web player.